# Finding element with no id, class or name (webdriver/Eclipse/Java/automation)

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, xpath, automation

I'm trying to create a basic login automated test but the `submit` button on the page doesn't have a unique `class name, and id`, so how do I locate it?

The HTML for the button is below:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="float:right;width:120px">Sign in</button>
```

There is a forgot password button that shares the same class but different 'type':

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="float:left;width:140px;padding-left:10px" onclick="showForgotPassword()">Forgotten Password?</button>
```

I have tried below code, but it didn't work for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-primary")).click();
```

Please help if you can guys, and look forward to hearing from you all.

Comment: You could 1) add an id to the element, or 2) (Selenium example) assuming this page will rarely change, find by element text
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'My Button')]")`

Comment: Are you not able to access element using the code you;ve shared?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include search by class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath and Firebug are not related to each other while running webdriver tests. You can always use xpath.

**EDITED:**

You can still test your xpath expressions in Firefox by opening Developer Tools (press F12) -> click on Console tab and enter your expression using command $x("%xPath%"), in your case command should look like so:

```
$x("//button[text()='Sign in']")
```

Hit Enter and you will see output Array [element] in case one element mathces, Array [element1, element2] if multiple matches were found and Array [ ] if nothing matches your expression.

**Regarding the How to locate your button, here are few solutions:**

1) (Assuming the id 'loginField' I provided is actually the id of your login field) You can just use submit() method on the element of login/password

```
// Or just reference the login field as you did before, doesn't have to be id
WebElement loginField = driver.findElement(By.id("loginField"));
loginField.submit();
```

2) You can call it via xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Sign in']")).click();
```

3) Regarding the className - you will need to use cssSelector instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary[type='submit']")).click();
```

This is because className doesn't work well for multiple classes, and when you have a space in class attribute of the element it means it's a member of both "btn" and "btn-primary" classes, but not that it's a member of "btn btn-primary" class.

Comment: where is the `loginField` in the question you've used?

Comment: it's assumed id of the login field code for which is not provided

Comment: not every element necessarily has an `id`.. *it's assumed id* might fail in that case.

Comment: No it doesn't... OP says *I cannot use xpath because firebug no longer works as an add on in firefox.* and there is not such field as `id`, other than that className has already been tried.

Comment: I'm not asking to reference field with ID. That is not even the Sign in button. Can you carefully re-read my post? And the line about firebug does not make much sense to me. Which I also addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Sign in']")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Based upon the button text `Sign in`, Use above `xpath` to click on `Sign in` button.

Comment: Hi Jainish, thank you for this. It is quite complex and I am trying to follow it but the wrong button has been referenced

Comment: HTML for the button is in the question above, the 'submit' button. I put the other button you have referenced to show that they share the same class, which is where the difficulty was coming from

Comment: I have provided the proper explanation of each xpath, So i guess you should accept my answer. Because Through this explanation you can able to create relative xpath.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it and do update me.

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your issue.